# Multiple links <a> and corresponding <div> with same class name jQuery click function

Tags: jquery

I am having a form which lists some entities along with a link (details) that on clicked will toggle the display of the corresponding details block for that link. Right now, I see that I am able to toggle the details block of the first entity if only one is present. But if there are two entities present, I can only toggle the second link... Following is my .gsp file

```
<% existingMedplans.each { existingMedplan -> %>

   <a href="#" class="detailsLink">Details</a>
   <span id="button">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
   </span>
   <span class="planItemDetails">
      <span id="order_label">Dose:</span>
      <span id="order_value">${existingMedplan.dose}</span>
   </span>
<% } %>
```

The jQuery code is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jq(".detailsLink").click(function(){
      jq(this).nextAll(".planItemDetails").toggle();
   });
</script>
```

My display is something like this:

Order_1  (detailsLink)

[Details displayed or hidden ]

Order_2  (detailsLink)

[Details displayed or hidden ]

In this case, clicking the second link loads the block that shows the details of Order_2, but clicking the link corresponding to Order_1 does not show anything. 'existingMedplans' is the list of objects that I want to display. How can I fix this?

Comment: Rather than `.nextAll()` try `.next()`

Comment: .next() / .next().next() / .next(".planItemDetails") didn't recognize it..

Answer (score 0):

OK..I found my error - I had my script inside my gsp code..inside the form..moved it out and now it works fine..